# How to merge rows startdate enddate based on column values using Lag Lead or window functions?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions, ranking-functions

I have a table with 4 columns: ID, STARTDATE, ENDDATE and BADGE. I want to merge rows based on ID and BADGE values but make sure that only consecutive rows will get merged.

For example, If input is:

[image]

Output will be:

[image]

I have tried lag lead, unbounded, bounded precedings but unable to achieve the output:

```
SELECT ID, 
       STARTDATE, 
       MAX(ENDDATE), 
       NAME 
FROM (SELECT USERID, 
             IFF(LAG(NAME) over(Partition by USERID Order by STARTDATE) = NAME, 
                 LAG(STARTDATE) over(Partition by USERID Order by STARTDATE), 
                 STARTDATE) AS STARTDATE, 
             ENDDATE, 
             NAME 
      from myTable ) 
GROUP BY USERID, 
         STARTDATE, 
         NAME
```

We have to make sure that we merge only consective rows having same ID and Badge.

Help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: @lemon, of course. I am able to merge 2 rows only using lag or lead. But here there might be possible to merge 3 rows or N consecutive rows. 

SELECT ID,
       STARTDATE,
       MAX(ENDDATE),
       NAME
FROM (
  SELECT USERID, IFF(LAG(NAME) over(Partition by USERID Order by STARTDATE) = NAME, LAG(STARTDATE) over(Partition by USERID Order by STARTDATE), STARTDATE) AS STARTDATE, ENDDATE, NAME from myTable
)   
GROUP BY USERID, STARTDATE, NAME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the problem into two steps:

- creating the right partitions
- aggregating on the partitions with direct aggregation functions (`MIN` and `MAX`)

You can approach the first step using a boolean field that is 1 when there's no consecutive date match (`row1.ENDDATE = row2.STARTDATE + 1 day`). This value will indicate when a new partition should be created. Hence if you compute a running sum, you should have your correctly numbered partitions.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           IFF(LAG(ENDDATE) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, Badge ORDER BY STARTDATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY = STARTDATE , 0, 1) AS boolval
    FROM tab 
)
SELECT *
       SUM(COALESCE(boolval, 0)) OVER(ORDER BY ID DESC, STARTDATE) AS rn
FROM cte
```

Then the second step can be summarized in the direct aggregation of "*STARTDATE*" and "*ENDDATE*" using the `MIN` and `MAX` function respectively, grouping on your ranking value. For syntax correctness, you need to add "*ID*" and "*Badge*" too in the `GROUP BY` clause, even though their range of action is already captured by the computed ranking value.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           IFF(LAG(ENDDATE) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, Badge ORDER BY STARTDATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY = STARTDATE , 0, 1) AS boolval
    FROM tab 
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT *,
           SUM(COALESCE(boolval, 0)) OVER(ORDER BY ID DESC, STARTDATE) AS rn
    FROM cte
)
SELECT ID,
       MIN(STARTDATE) AS STARTDATE,
       MAX(ENDDATE) AS ENDDATE,
       Badge
FROM cte2
GROUP BY ID,
         Badge,
         rn
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, let me try this, and I will come back to you.

Comment: Perfect, very clever. Making the right partition was the key to the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Snowflake, such gaps and island problem can be solved using
function [conditional_true_event](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional_true_event.html#conditional-true-event)

As below query -
First CTE, creates a column to indicate a change event (true or false) when a value changes for column badge.

Next CTE (cte_1) using this change event column with function `conditional_true_event` produces another column (increment if change is TRUE) to be used as grouping, in the final main query.

And, final query is just min, max group by.

```
with cte as (
  select
  m.*,
  case when badge <> lag(badge) over (partition by id order by null)
  then true
  else false end flag
from merge_tab m
), cte_1 as (
  select c.*,
  conditional_true_event(flag) over (partition by id order by null) cn
from cte c
)
select id,min(startdate) ms, max(enddate) me, badge
from cte_1
group by id,badge,cn
order by id desc, ms asc, me asc, badge asc;
```

Final output -

| ID | MS | ME | BADGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 51 | 1985-02-01 | 2019-04-28 | 1 |
| 51 | 2019-04-29 | 2020-08-16 | 2 |
| 51 | 2020-08-17 | 2021-04-03 | 3 |
| 51 | 2021-04-04 | 2021-04-05 | 1 |
| 51 | 2021-04-06 | 2022-08-20 | 2 |
| 51 | 2022-08-21 | 9999-12-31 | 3 |
| 10 | 2020-02-06 | 9999-12-31 | 3 |

With data -

```
select * from merge_tab;
```

| ID | STARTDATE | ENDDATE | BADGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 51 | 1985-02-01 | 2019-04-28 | 1 |
| 51 | 2019-04-29 | 2019-04-28 | 2 |
| 51 | 2019-09-16 | 2019-11-16 | 2 |
| 51 | 2019-11-17 | 2020-08-16 | 2 |
| 51 | 2020-08-17 | 2021-04-03 | 3 |
| 51 | 2021-04-04 | 2021-04-05 | 1 |
| 51 | 2021-04-06 | 2022-05-05 | 2 |
| 51 | 2022-05-06 | 2022-08-20 | 2 |
| 51 | 2022-08-21 | 9999-12-31 | 3 |
| 10 | 2020-02-06 | 2019-04-28 | 3 |
| 10 | 2021-03-21 | 9999-12-31 | 3 |